# While deploying laravel project on bluehost shared hosting's addon domain, but I am getting "403 forbidden" error

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting, bluehost

While deploying laravel project on bluehost shared hosting's addon domain, but I am getting "403 forbidden" error:

My hosting folder structure as below:

public_html:

```
app1 (main domain)
 |__app1 folders/files
laravelapp (addon domain)
 |__laravelapp folders/files
      |__app
      |__public
      |__other folders/files etc
```

Now I have fillup all ".env" file parameters including database also.

Also I have given required permission to the folders.

Also I have hit mulitple laravel cache clearing commands.

".htacess" file inside public folder as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    //Added following "IfModule tag" for setup
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /laravelapp/public
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I am getting "403 forbidden" error for that laravel application.

Please help to resolve above issue.

Comment: There are many, many reasons for this 403. Point your domain to your laravelapp public directory, maybe bluehost uses `www` or `public_htm`, so make sure it matches. Does bluehost use Apache as webserver?

Comment: its important the host points to the public folder as root

Comment: I have setup "new document root" as "public_html/laravelapp/public" for "laravelapp" project. Actually behind scene bluehost creates subdomain for addons like "laravelapp.maindomain.com". But my actual domain url is "laravelapp.com"

Comment: set permission 755 for whole folder in terminal if you have ssh access.
or make it executable and readable by anyone.

Comment: Its solved when I have matched the cpanel and laravel-app's php-version and also I have added slash at the end of APP_URL attribute of '.env'.. then I hit necessory commands to update and cache clear. Thank you for your help.